# Changing the layout of a navigation bar on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I created a nav bar and was wondering how I could edit the CSS of it on wordpress and by that I mean calling the nav bars by it's name( from php to css I suppose).

As it's just two dots showing variables.

This is what I have as nav bar.(It works even though there are no variables there).

```
    function register_my_menu(){
    register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Test' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu');
```

I have no idea how I should edit this in the style.css as I am new to wordpress but have common knowledge on php/css yet this keeps me questioning all the time.

Comment: How does the `html` result look like?

Comment: Just two dots with the variables(It's a custom theme I was given that is basically bald) I figured out that if you for ex. turned on twenty something theme that it'd edit the menu into a normal one by itself so I guess the one I was given is nearly empty as it gave me only li's with no make-up.

I have no idea how to give it a good look though, it doesn't seem logical to me..

Comment: And the `ul` has no class as far as I understand?

Comment: Well, if the menu is the the first `ul-li` on the page, you can access with pseudo-element feature.

Comment: Could you explain this to me?

Comment: Posted it as answer. Too much code for comment.

Comment: Let's say I add this to css: .navbar{ border:1px; background-color:#FFF }. It still wouldn't change it on view for some reason, as I don't know how exactly I can modify something with css I added through php on wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>

<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>10</li>
   <li>20</li>
</ul>


<style>
body ul:first-child {
    background: red;
}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea but this is standard css/html which I know how it works. The issue is that I add stuff on wordpress through php with register_nav_menu. Then I'd like it to have make-up and for some reason standard css'ing like I know it doesn't have any effect, like for example classes to brackets and then background color.